# Laravel HTTP status code "1" is not valid error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to access my url at: `http://localhost/app/public/questions/1`

My Routes

```
 $this->get('/questions/{question_id}','questionController@show');
```

My controller

```
public function show($question_id) {

    $showQuestion=questions::findOrFail($question_id);
    return redirect('questions',compact('showQuestion'));
}
```

For some reason I'm getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 458:
The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to return a view

```
public function show($question_id) {

    $showQuestion=questions::findOrFail($question_id);
    return view('questions')->with('question', $showQuestion);
}
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

After having something similar myself, maybe you should be using:

```
return redirect('questions')->with('showQuestion', $showQuestion);
```